# C++ delete statement throws Heap corrupted exception in .net 4.5 process

Tags: .net, visual-c++, memory-management, com, heap-corruption

Earlier i had a .net client application (console application) whose target framework is set as 4.0.
The client code looks like ,

```
    COMProxyCustomClass proxy = new COMProxyCustomClass();
    proxy.LoadFieldServiceComponent("abc", 3);
```

where the .net client make use of C++ COM type COMProxyCustom via reference to a RCW interop dll generated by importing TLB of the C++ com project.
The implementation of LoadFieldServiceComponent method looks like ,

```
    STDMETHODIMP CCOMProxyCustom::LoadFieldServiceComponent(BSTR fscName, int version)
    {
   HRESULT hr = S_OK;   
   ILocaleManager *localeManager = NULL;
   hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_LocaleManager, NULL , CLSCTX_ALL , IID_ILocaleManager,      (void**)&localeManager);
   delete(localeManager);
   localeManager = NULL;
   return hr;
    }
```

Again here ILocaleManager is a .net type which gets used in the C++ project by exporting a TLB from the .net project and including/importing it here in the C++ com project.

```
    #import "SomeInterop.tlb" no_namespace named_guids
```

Till here everything is alright.

Here comes the problem , to make use of the features provided by .net 4.5 (System.IO.Compression) i moved the C# client project now to target .net 4.5 version(earlier it was .net 4.0). After doing this migration , i started getting a heap corrupted error at the statement **delete(localeManager)**.

[image: Error message from VS debugger]

Now why do we get this error when this particular statement (delete) gets executed in a .net process which targets 4.5 and why not in 4.0 , is there any change in how the memory should be freed in C++ code if the .net application which loads this C++ code targets 4.5 framework version ? and how to clear the memory of localeManager now if delete cant be used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using COM, you should call Release() on localeManager instead of deleting it.

```
 if (localeManager)
     localeManager->Release();
```

COM use reference count to manage object life cycle.

As C++ delete key word, it has to know the type of the pointer, it relies on C++ [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) to works; as  to COM, it has different RTTI implementation. COM object has different layout structure than C++ object.

As you said, delete works earlier, it really doesn't. Deleting that a COM pointer will corruptthe heap, however, it won't crash at the line of delete statement; the behavior is: your program sometime crashes, sometime not.

Comment: Yes , i understand that . But do you have any idea why the delete statement worked earlier and not now ? i would like to understand more about the delete part.

Comment: @srsyogesh modified my answer

Comment: Thanks @Matt , though i was aware of the fact that we need to release the COM objects using Release method i didn't realize that delete statement was used to free up the memory till now in the application . But interestingly i focused more towards why it worked earlier and why not now .Was thinking may be new .net framework 4.5 might have introduced this kind of behavior and if so what was it , this was the excitement which made me to post this question . Anyways thanks again for your explanation.

Comment: @srsyogesh one not, this is not introduce by .NET. COM is 'older' than .NET